# microk8s disable kubeflow file disable.kubeflow.sh errors

Tags: kubeflow, microk8s

I'm trying to disable kubeflow on microk8s.  I installed/ enabled kubeflow using:

```sh
# install MicroK8s
sudo snap install microk8s --classic

# update ufw to allow pop-pop and pod-internet comms
sudo ufw allow in on cni0 && sudo ufw allow out on cni0
sudo ufw default allow routed

# update permissions
sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER
sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube

# --- RESTART MACHINE ---

# check installation
microk8s status --wait-ready

# enable core-dns and local storage etc
microk8s enable dns dashboard storage

# install kubeflow
microk8s enable kubeflow
```

I now want to disable it using `microk8s disable kubeflow`.  The message i get is:

```sh
$ microk8s disable kubeflow
  File "/snap/microk8s/2213/scripts/wrappers/common/../../../actions/disable.kubeflow.sh", line 52
    click.echo(f"Destroying Kubeflow {resource}...")
```

What am i doing wrong?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with the MicroK8s Kubeflow add-on, you can try a few alternatives:

1. Install the Kubeflow Charmed Operators directly following the
   respective documentation using MicroK8s as a Kubernetes.
2. Refresh your MicroK8s installation to the tip version via `sudo snap refresh microk8s --classic --channel=edge` . This might be useful if a fix has been released in the edge channel of the MicroK8s snap and not yet in the default stable channel.
3. Re-install the tip version of MicroK8s with `sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=edge` , and re-enable the Kubeflow add-on.

https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/microk8s/kubeflow-on-microk8s/#troubleshooting

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.